# Rename CodeIgniter's Cross-site Request Forgery Cookie

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, csrf

I've tried to rename the CodeIgniter CSRF cookie by editing the values in `config/config.php`:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'mysite_csrf';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'mysite_csrf';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

But when I visit the site, the cookie still shows as: `ci_csrf_token`.

Why might this be occuring?

Comment: Are you deleting the old cookie before testing the new name?

Comment: @roflwaffle Yes, I have.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of CI are you using? There was an error in 2.0.x

https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/issue/199

Comment: Yes, I'm using v2.0.2. Any idea when 2.0.3 with the fix is to be released?